# zsh: event not found: /bin/bash -- syntax error

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

file.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

if { true }
then echo "hi"
fi
```

I have this within a shell-script. Upon trying to run, I get:

```
% ./file.sh
./brackets.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./brackets.sh: line 4: `then echo "hi"'
```

Running in my shell:

```
% #!/bin/bash

if { true }
then echo "hi"
fi
zsh: event not found: /bin/bash
```

Running again in my shell:

```
% if { true }
then echo "hi"
fi
hi
```

so the issue is with `!/bin/bash`. Anyone know what's going on? I looked online but all the posts on it are far in the past and it seems like the users weren't doing this inside a file/shellscript.

I am on MacOS Ventura, running zsh.

To be clear, I'm not asking you to fix my program. I'm just curious what's wrong with it as is, for learning purposes. I'm using `{}` because I was messing with the exit statuses.

Comment: `{ true }` doesn't mean what you think it does; the `}` is an argument to the `true` command.

Comment: I thought `#!/bin/bash` is the standard shebang @Jetchisel ?

Comment: That's definitely why @ruakh . Could you tell me what it does? There's no info on it on the man pages.

Comment: It does nothing, because `true` ignores its arguments (other than potentially checking for `--help` and `--version`). The point is that you don't want the `}` to be an argument to `true`, so you need a newline or semicolon before it. (Or you can just drop the curly braces, which aren't needed in this context — not even if you have multiple commands in there.)

Comment: It's pointless to do a `#!/bin/bash` in an interactive zsh. What do you expect from it? The actual reason for the _event not found_ error message is that the exclamation mark is the history-expansion character in an interactive zsh.

Comment: The error in your bash script is simply that the curly braces don't make sense. Here again, I wonder what you are want to achieve.

Comment: Having said this: You have two completely unrelated problems: One is in your bash program, and the other one is related to a command run in an interactive zsh. Don't put more than one problem into a single question. In particular, the zsh error message is not related to programming at all (because it's in an interactive shell) and should be posted at [su] instead of Stackoverflow.

Comment: Run your script through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) -- it'll point out that you need a `;` (or line break) before the `}` in order for it to be treated as a keyword rather than just an argument to the `true` command (message [SC1083](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC1083)). But also, you don't need the `{ }` at all, because what comes between `if` and `then` can already be a list of commands. I think you're confused about basic shell syntax.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using zsh instead of bash, you can start your file with:

```
#!/bin/zsh
```

Also, there is no need for curly braces around `true`. So this should work:

```
#!/bin/zsh

if true
then echo "hi"
fi
```

Note that you can also run the above file with `bash`.

```
bash file.sh
```

Comment: I'm testing with the curly braces. I wanted to extend it to things like `{true; false}` where `true` and `false` are any commands. My question is why it's not working as is.

Comment: @cspurposesonly, do you know what is the purpose of curly braces? at least in `bash`.

Comment: I thought that it is to tell the interpreter to treat what is within as one command, only returning the exit status of the last command run to what is outside it @Jetchisel